# OptimalBits/bull For Java

Tags: java, spring, redis

I recently came across this interesting project for Redis based queue for nodejs application.

https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull

My question is - do we have something similar for Java based applications? Bull for java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of the complexity of your application you can probably implements it easily using the core API using Jedis or Lettuce Java client, and the proper datastructure.

Also if you need something "richer" and closer to Bull you can look at [Redisson](https://redisson.pro/).

Let us know which kind of features you need in your application and maybe the Redis community can give you more details about implementation using the core data structure, if you do not want to use Redisson.